# iOS 8 or later on iPhone 4

Tags: iphone, ios, upgrade, jailbreak

I searched a way to upgrade my jailbreak iphone 4 with 7.1.2 iOS to 8 or later iOS, but none of them work (one proposed "[solution](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rq0p-6oPJ44)" is to download ifile and change the name of the iOS; this is a bad joke). On this forum there are similar question, but they are too old for this reason I decided to ask this question.

Answer (score 3):

As of date, there is no official way to upgrade iPhone 4 to any iOS after iOS 7.1.2 and iPhone 4s can't be upgraded to any iOS after iOS 9.3.6

Comment: Hi @an4s911 I'm looking for an unofficial way to do that...maybe some developer did it.

Comment: I'm Sorry, I have no knowledge about that. :(